# ggplot with wait to referral and wait to appointments

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I have a database of 350 patients with their income, the time that they waited for a referral and the time they waited for an appointment. This simulates the data:

```
set.seed(1)
income<-sort(rep(seq(10,105,5),20))
referral<-runif(400,10,20)+income
appointment<-referral+runif(400,10,20)+income

df<-data.frame(cbind(income,referral,appointment))

df<-df[order(df$income,df$referral),]
```

I would like a plot that has on the x axis the income, one observation per patient, and on the y axis a line that starts at the time to referral and finishes at the time to time to the first appointment. I do not know what this plot is called (high-low?) but I have mocked up what I would like it to look like below.

[image: mock up of reguired plot]

Can anyone suggest some ggplot code to help me produce my plot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geom_segment()` layer is hard to dodge as it will only dodge one of the two x-positions. Instead, I recommend calculating the correct dodge before plotting.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
income<-sort(rep(seq(10,105,5),20))
referral<-runif(400,10,20)+income
appointment<-referral+runif(400,10,20)+income

df<-data.frame(cbind(income,referral,appointment))

df<-df[order(df$income,df$referral),]

# Calculate dodges
dodge_width <- 0.8
df$dodge <- unlist(lapply(split(df$income, df$income), function(x) {
  seq(-0.5 * dodge_width, 0.5 * dodge_width, length.out = length(x))
}))

# Convert to pseudo-discrete position
df$position <- match(df$income, sort(unique(df$income)))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = position + dodge, xend = position + dodge, 
        y = referral, yend = appointment, group = seq_along(income),
        colour = income)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = df$position[!duplicated(df$position)],
    labels = df$income[!duplicated(df$position)]
  ) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    colours = c("red", "yellow", "green")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

according to what the coloring to be done ? I assumed income.

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(x=income,y=referral,color=(income),group = income))+
scale_color_gradient2(low = "darkred", mid = "red", high = "green")+
geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The colour is by income. How is the appointment time used in your solution? If  appointment is used, then each line will be variable in length. Also I was expecting 400 lines.